# Accessing the Camera through WKWebView in an iOS App

Tags: javascript, ios

Based on an example, I added the following Javascript into a web page that is used by an iOS app written in Swift. I'm seeking to get the web page to access the camera without bridging into Swfit.

With the following code sample loaded on a webview, the Android app was able to access the camera, however the iPhone app did not display it.  It did ask for permission to use, but then nothing happen, no errors displayed - the element remained blank.

```
openCam() {
    let All_mediaDevices = navigator.mediaDevices
    if (!All_mediaDevices || !All_mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
        console.log("getUserMedia() not supported.");
        return;
    }
    All_mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        audio: true,
        video: true
    })
        .then(function (vidStream) {
            var video = document.getElementById('videoCam');
            if ("srcObject" in video) {
                video.srcObject = vidStream;
            } else {
                video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(vidStream);
            }
            video.onloadedmetadata = function (e) {
                video.play();
            };
        })
        .catch(function (e) {
            console.log(e.name + ": " + e.message);
        });
}
```

Does `WKWebView` block access in to the camera or is there a different way to do so? Is there a different way to access it in JS?